# Is it possible to make Laravel password reset use custom column names?

Tags: php, laravel

In my database the column for passwords is called 'password_hash'. I have managed to make login and registration work properly, but password reset is trying to update the column password and failing with the following error message:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'password' in 'field list'
```

Is there a way for me to make password reset use my custom column name?

EDIT: The way I made login work was by adding

```
public function getAuthPassword() {
    return $this->password_hash;
}
```

To the User model.

The way I made registration work was by overriding the create function in the RegisterController since I needed to add some relationships anyway.

Comment: Do you use default `php artisan make:auth` logic? By the way you can make your own controller for this. Take a look on `Auth` traits and make similar.

Comment: Important thing is how did you manage it to work? Please update your question with it.

Comment: @Bart I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you must be make `RedirectsUsers`  trait extends `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RedirectsUsers` end there override all `password` field to `costom_password`